# SwipeRefresh layout progress bar is not hiding even after completion

Tags: java, android

I am using MVVM pattern in which I am using SwipeRefresh layout to refresh recycler view in my layout.When I am pulling it then it continue to refresh even after method completed successfully.

Below is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            userRepository.getUserList();

        }
    });
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public void getUserList(){

          Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
          ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

          Call<List<User>> userList = apiService.getUser();

          userList.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, final Response<List<User>> response) {

                  Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() throws Exception {

                              if(response.body() != null) {

                                  List<User> list = response.body();

                                  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                                      String id = list.get(i).get_id();
                                      String names = list.get(i).getName();
                                      String age = list.get(i).getAge();

                                      User user = new User(id,names,age);

                                      userDb.userDao().Insert(user);

                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {

                                Toast.makeText(context,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                  Toast.makeText(context,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          });

}
```

Method fetching list is in another class **UserRepository** and I am calling method in another activity **MainActivity**.I am not getting any way how can I stop refreshing process.Someone please let me know a way to stop refreshing process.
Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the progress dialog add this,

```
swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Comment: in onRefresh(), after you get your userList